# In C, what happen if define a variable with undefined thing?

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

I have an example code like this:

```
int var;
var = MACRO_A;
```

I expect the `MACRO_A` has been defined like this:

```
#define MACRO_A    1234
```

However, I can **not** find the `MACRO_A` defined anywhere in the source code, but I can build the code successfully, so what is the value of `var` at the end ?

The compiler is gcc.

Comment: Use `gcc -C -E source.c > source.i` to get the preprocessed form, and look inside...

Comment: @eepty if you find my answer useful, please feel free to upvote and choose my post as the answer.

Comment: @cnicutar , @Sangeeth Saravanaraj , @Basile Starynkevitch I am writing a software for an embedded device, and I am using the Atmel Studio5 IDE in Windows, sorry all but I am not sure how to check the -D option and the `gcc -C -E source.c > source.i`. I have tried to read the build option in the IDE but I can not find these options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That macro could have been passed during compilation with `-D` option.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = MACRO_A;
    printf("MACRO_A : %d \n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc macro.c -D MACRO_A=10
$ ./a.out 
MACRO_A : 10 
$
```

Comment: Often, the `-DMACRO_A=10` argument to the compiler is buried in the build process, e.g. `Makefile`-s, `autoconf`, etc etc. I recommend checking it with `#ifdef` and issue a meaningful `#error` otherwise...

Answer (score 2):

> However, I can not find the MACRO_A defined anywhere in the source
>   code, but I can build the code successfully, so what is the value of
>   var at the end

It's there somewhere or it wouldn't compile. Perhaps it's defined directly on the command line ? (`-DMACRO_A`)